# why does MediaStore.insertImage return null sometime

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

this is my code
i get this exception some times.Is it becus of DCIM/storage folder 
how can i avoid this problem
this is my code
i get this exception some times.Is it becus of DCIM/storage folder 
how can i avoid this problem
this is my code
i get this exception some times.Is it becus of DCIM/storage folder 
how can i avoid this problem

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/30971 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.mobisys.biod.questabird/com.mobisys.biod.questagame.SightingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3700)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3743)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:172)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:468)
at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:458)
at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:430)
at com.mobisys.biod.questagame.SightingActivity.getImageUri(SightingActivity.java:620)
at com.mobisys.biod.questagame.SightingActivity.onActivityResult(SightingActivity.java:944)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5732)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3696)
... 11 more
```

Comment: sometime mean ? does it work sometime ?

Comment: yes it works but in some cases it does'nt

Comment: the crash is on moto g 3 with marshmellow

Comment: You mean this is always crashed in moto g3 but not in others. Is this some cases of orientation changes or something ?